# Interrupt the execution of a googleapis method

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

I use the **googleapis** (Google APIs Node.js Client) library method `googleapis.drive.files.create()` to upload a file to the cloud.
I pass the method a **fs.ReadStream** as one of the parameters (`fs.createReadStream()`)

Are there any ways to interrupt the execution of the `googleapis.drive.files.create()` method (with or without error)?

```
const body = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
await this.googleDriveClient.files.create(
  {
    resource: {
      name: fileName,
      parents: [parentIds]
    },
    media: {
      mimeType: 'image/gif',
      body
    },
  });
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more context on why do you need that?

Comment: Please read [ask] edit your question and include [example] and describe in a little more detail what your issue is.

Comment: @Martí there is a case when the Internet connection is lost and this method freezes
I would like to somehow pass control back to the calling code
`const body = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
await this.googleDriveClient.files.create({
  resource: {
    name: fileName,
    parents: [parentIds]
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'audio/mpeg',
    body
  },
});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As the NodeJS library's `README.md` exmplains](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/#request-options), it uses gaxios underneath it and allows you to pass options either globally or for each call. [See the list of gaxios request options](https://github.com/googleapis/gaxios#request-options).

If for some reason you want to manually handle when to abort instead of something more usual like setting a timeout, gaxios has an option called `signal`.

### References

- [Request options - Google APIs Node.js Client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/#request-options)
- [Request options - Gaxios](https://github.com/googleapis/gaxios#request-options)